# how to fix "redis session expire automatically"

Tags: codeigniter, session, redis

I am using codeigniter and redis for sessions.After some time session is expiring.I don't want session to expire unless logout is clicked.

Redis is configure on server but it is not  working as expected

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'redis';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 0;
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'tcp://localhost:6379';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 3000000000;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

I want session to work forever.

Comment: what does sometime mean ? did you check if redis got crashed? Because if you didn't setup the backup file - redis will lose all data

Comment: after some time i mean after few mins around 30 mins.

Comment: yeah i'm not sure if the value of `sess_expiration` in your config is the correct one - try something like `$config['sess_expiration'] = 31536000;` (for one year e.g.) - but keep in mind the words forever and redis doesn't really match ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have also same issue but it resolved after setup DNS local connection configuration setting Please check image for setting.[DNS local connection setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xcy2Q.png) . OR update redis server version.